# Easy way to import/export Sql Server 2005 users/permissions across instances?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there an easy way to export and then import users/permissions from one Sql Server 2005 instance to another?

Comment: Just for reference. There is a default way from MS. See here: [Microsoft KB Entry for that][1]
[1]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133/de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the management console to generate a script for your users and thier associated permissions.  Same can be done for the server logins in the security folder.

Select your user:
Select DB and expand security\users folder
Right Click --> Script User As --> Create To --> New Query

For Logins

Select your Login:
Expand security\logins folder
Right Click --> Script Login As --> Create To --> New Query

Now just run the query on your new instance.  Just choose the db to run the script in.

Answer (score 3):

Might need to do a "sp_change_users_login AUTO_FIX, 'my_user'" afterwards to re-link security logins to their respective data as well.

Answer (score 1):

sqlcmd  -E  -d master -S suksql01 -Q "sp_help_revlogin" -o \suksql03\login\LOGIN.txt
go
exec sp_help_revlogin
go

exec sp_help_login

Comment: This wont work in most systems because that is not a standard SQL Server sp. You need to first create sp_help_revlogin http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992